# Unable to switch from Fragment to Activity / Activity to Fragment in Android Programming

Tags: android, android-activity, hyperlink, switch-statement, fragment

Currently, I am mainly using Fragments to connect to Facebook.

However, for the other codes, I am using normal activites (no Fragments).

My issue now is that I wish to have a button to link from my "Home Page" to the Fragment, and from the Fragment back to my "Home Page"

I am unable to do so.

I tried to use the same code to switch between activities for this but it does not work.

Is there a way to Link Normal Activities to Fragments and Vice Versa ? Or can they only link to each other ?

This is my Code:

```
    public class SplashFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);
//   return view;

    Button btnNextScreen = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNextScreen);      
//    Button btnNextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextScreen);

    //Listening to button event
    btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View arg0) {
          //Starting a new Intent
          Intent nextScreen = new Intent(**getApplicationContext()**, SecondScreenActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextScreen);

}
});

 return view;   
}
}
```

I am getting an error at getApplicationContext().

If I change it to getActivity(), they will prompt with another error that they are expecting to switch to a Fragment, not an activity.

Thank you for your help !

Regards,
AndroidStudent

Answer (score 1):

use this getActivity() if u want to navigate from fragment to activity.

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondScreenActivity.class);
startActivity(nextScreen);
```

Comment: First it gives

"Unable to find explicit activity class have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"


after I added it in AndroidManifest:

 <activity android:name="SecondScreenActivity"></activity>

 I got this error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity (com.mp2012.ieatishootipost/com.mp2012.ieatishootipost.SecondScreenActivity]: java.lang.Illegal Argument Exception: No view found for id 0x7f040003 for fragment SelectionFragment {413408b0 #0 id=0x7f040003}

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), activityname.class); 
i.putExtra("key", value);           
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am also unable to find the class from fragment then I write this code and it works;
public class userprofile extends Fragment  {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_userprofile, container, false);

    final ImageView iconoptions = view.findViewById(R.id.iconoptions);

    iconoptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),com.example.miniproject. options.class));
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}