# Fragment to activity and go back to the fragment

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, android-intent

how can i intent back from (activity1-> fragment1) actually my design concept is like ( fragment1-> activity1-> fragment1) in fragment1 i click the data it bring me to activity1 for edit purpose or either update the data or remove the data after click either both button it will bring me back to the fragment1 and look the overall data but my problem is i click either both button it will jump out from the app, how can i solve this problem? using intent or ?

the code below is  Update_detail_info ( activity1 )

```
 public class Update_detail_info extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        EditText weight,bodyf,timef,datef,commentf;
        Button btnUpdate, btnRemove;
        long weight_id;

        SQLControlerWeight dbcon;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_detail_info);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            dbcon = new SQLControlerWeight(this);
            dbcon.openDatabase();

            btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_update);
            btnRemove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_remove);

            Intent i = getIntent();
            String weightID = i.getStringExtra("weightId");
            String dN = i.getStringExtra("dateNum");
            String tN = i.getStringExtra("timeNum");
            String wN =  i.getStringExtra("weightNum");
            String bN =  i.getStringExtra("bodyFatNum");
            String cM =  i.getStringExtra("comment");

            weight_id = Long.parseLong(weightID);

            datef.setText(dN);
            timef.setText(tN);
            weight.setText(wN);
            bodyf.setText(bN);
            commentf.setText(cM);

           btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
           btnRemove.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button_update:
                    String d_update = datef.getText().toString();
                    String t_update = timef.getText().toString();
                    String w_update = weight.getText().toString();
                    String b_update = bodyf.getText().toString();
                    String c_update = commentf.getText().toString();


                    dbcon.updateNote(weight_id,w_update,b_update,d_update,t_update,c_update);

                    this.returnHome();
                    break;

                case R.id.button_remove:
                    dbcon.deleteNote(weight_id);
                    this.returnHome();
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void returnHome() { // is that here the code are wrong ? cause i need to jump back to the previous fragment1 

            Intent home_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    HistoryF.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(home_intent);
        }


    }


                    break;
        }
```

code below is the fragment for HistoryF ( fragment1)

```
 public class HistoryF  extends Fragment {

        View contentView;
        ListView list;
        SQLControlerWeight dbconnection;
        TextView weight_num, date_num, time_num, bf_num, comment,weight_ID;
        private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_fragment, container, false);

            dbconnection = new SQLControlerWeight(getActivity());
            dbconnection.openDatabase();
            list = (ListView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.listViewWeight);

            Cursor cursor = dbconnection.readNote();

            String[] from = new String[]{
                    DBHelperNote.WEIGHT_ID,
                    DBHelperNote.WEIGHT_NUM,
                    DBHelperNote.BODY_FAT,
                    DBHelperNote.WEIGHT_DATE,
                    DBHelperNote.WEIGHT_TIME,
                    DBHelperNote.WEIGHT_COMMENTS

            };
            int[] to = new int[]{
                    R.id.weight_id,
                    R.id.weight_num,
                    R.id.bf_num,
                    R.id.date_num,
                    R.id.time_num,
                    R.id.comment_text
            };

            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                   contentView.getContext(), R.layout.history, cursor, from, to,0);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.setAdapter(adapter);


            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    weight_ID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.weight_id);
                    weight_num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.weight_num);
                    bf_num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bf_num);
                    date_num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_num);
                    time_num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_num);
                    comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);

                    String weightId = weight_ID.getText().toString();
                    String wn = weight_num.getText().toString();
                    String bfn = bf_num.getText().toString();
                    String dn = date_num.getText().toString();
                    String tn = time_num.getText().toString();
                    String cm = comment.getText().toString();

                    Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Update_detail_info.class);

                    modify_intent.putExtra("weightId", weightId);
                    modify_intent.putExtra("dateNum", dn);
                    modify_intent.putExtra("timeNum", tn);
                    modify_intent.putExtra("weightNum", wn);
                    modify_intent.putExtra("bodyFatNum", bfn);
                    modify_intent.putExtra("comment", cm);

                    startActivity(modify_intent);
                }
            });

        return contentView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

    }
```

this is my main activity for control the tab

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new KeyInWeightF(), "TRACK");
        adapter.addFragment(new HistoryF(), "HISTORY");
        adapter.addFragment(new AnalysisF(), "GRAPH");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to switch from Fragment to Activity / Activity to Fragment in Android Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795433/unable-to-switch-from-fragment-to-activity-activity-to-fragment-in-android-pro)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code on your returnHome()

```
Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(Update_detail_info.this); //get parent activity
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
NavUtils.navigateUpTo(Update_detail_info.this, intent); // and then navigate it to parent
```

or

```
 NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(Update_detail_info.this);
```

both worked same

and in your **manifest** file define parentActivity

manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.yourApp.MainActivity" ...>
        ...
    </activity>
    <!-- A child of the main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.yourApp.Update_detail_info"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_Update_detail"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.yourApp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.yourApp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

For more details to Providing **Up Navigation** go to this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).

And for understand **startactivityforresult** go to this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: sorry I just copy the code but it wont work. What you mean for the parent activity ? u mean my MainActivity?

Comment: yes, I mean your mainActivity. But if your activity1 is a temperory activity( fragment1-> activity1-> fragment1) then why you are not using startActivityForResult(intent, reqestcode) intead of startActivity(intent).

Comment: i dunno how can u gv me a guild show the sample code ? i just do what you say copy the code and place it in returnHome() but it wont work.
Did you mean like this 
Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(MainActivity.this); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
NavUtils.navigateUpTo(MainActivity.this, intent);

Comment: why you are writing MainActivity.this, this is the context of current activity.

Comment: Your problem is that, maybe you hadn't defined the parentActivity in your manifest.xml. See edit.